# What are the terms to describe sets in the set theoretic difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If I have a set theoretic difference A\B, what is the term given to these sets (e.g. like a * b, a is multiplier and b is multiplicand)?

Comment: Why should there be a term?

Comment: You could use terms similar to regular subtraction. According to Wikipedia, "Formally, the number being subtracted is known as the subtrahend, while the number it is subtracted from is the minuend." These terms aren't used frequently and I'm not sure if they are ever used in a set theoretic sense.

Comment: I have never seen any special terms used for the operands of a set difference (or of $\cup$ or $\cap$). It would make sense to borrow the terms  *minuend* and *subtrahend* from arithmetic subtraction for set difference but why would you want to do that? And, by the way, "multiplier" and "multiplicand" are generally only used when you are writing about multiplication as an algorithmic process (i.e., almost never in mathematics $\ddot{\smile}$): in abstract algebra, the terms $x$ and $y$ in the product $xy$ are called *factors*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard or commonly used terminology (though I would not call "multiplier" and "multiplicand" commonly used either).  If you must have a term, you could use "subtrahend" for $B$ and "minuend" for $A$, as with subtraction of numbers.  But don't expect others to know what you are talking about using these terms unless you define them.

Comment: Thank you. I will use these terms and define them. I got a few comments asking me why I would want to define them and the reason for it is because I am writing a report about set theoretic operations and my adviser told me to find and use their proper terms.